# ValidationError loses context

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

In my **forms.py** I raise an validation error when the user is already a member of the project. If i try to add a user who is already a member the validation error gets perfectly raised, but then I get redirected to the template and I have no context any more.

Any Best Practices in raising a form validation error? What am I doing wrong?

```
class AddUserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.project = kwargs.pop('project')
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(AddUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._user_cache = None

    def clean_user(self):
        """
        Check if the user is already a member of the project.
        """
        user = self.cleaned_data['user']

        if ProjectMember.objects.filter(project=self.project, user=user).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("User is already a member of this project."))

        # store user instance we queried for here to prevent additional lookups.
        self._user_cache = user

        return user
```

**views.py** without the ProjectUpdate view because it does not matter in this case. The views are a little bit complicated, because I have 2 forms in one template. If you know any better way to accomplish this, let me know.

```
class ProjectDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = ProjectDisplay.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'update_form' in request.POST:
            view = ProjectUpdate.as_view()
        elif 'add_user_form' in request.POST:
            view = ProjectAddUser.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

class ProjectDisplay(DetailView):
    model = Project

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectDisplay, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['update_form'] = ProjectUpdateForm(initial={
            'name': self.object.name,
            'description': self.object.description
        })
        context['add_user_form'] = AddUserForm(project=self.object, user=self.request.user)
        context['project'] = self.object
        context['is_member'] = self.object.user_is_member(self.request.user)
        return context

class ProjectAddUser(CreateView):
    model = ProjectMember
    form_class = AddUserForm
    template_name = 'projects/project_detail.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('project_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.get_object().slug})

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return Project.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ProjectAddUser, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'project': self.get_object()})
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

Comment: What do your template and urls look like? I don't think you are gaining much by using generic class based views here. If you need two forms on the page I think it would be easier to debug if you wrote your own function based view.

Comment: I switched over to function based views and now the validation problem does not occur any more. Is there any better way to accomplish two forms on a page with generic class based views? If not, function based views are probably much more convenient in this situation.